# Python for loop and if-statement. Unable to count words in *.csv file

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, increment, readline

I am a complete beginner at coding and Python.

I have spent, I don't want to admit, a ridiculous amount of hours on what I know should be a simple thing in Python.

1. open() method to open a *.csv file
2. read that file using a for loop
3. and then select a row using index and count how many times a word is there

I am trying not to use modules. Just Python and a for loop.

I will simply paste the info that I have in the csv file for testing purposes.

Can someone please HELP!

I was expecting to be naturally awesome at coding and I guess I am not.

```
date,rank,song title,artist,weeks-on-board
2022-10-25,1,This is love,doug,3
2022-10-26,2,Love sucks,steve,5
2022-10-27,3,Love love Love love,aaron,7
```

```py
#######################################################

# set the counter(accumulator) loveCount to equal 0
loveCount = 0


# use the python built in open() method to read a csv file
file = open("love.csv")


# read a line and go to the next line with readline() method
data = file.readline()


# start a loop that will love through the csv, strip off the 'ol
# backslash n, and split the csv into seperate words
for line in file:
    linelist = line.strip("\n").split(",")


# the [2] refers to 'index' two in the list and will display the str there
# Also, .lower() makes all the str lowercase, so if I could get this to
# work would, wouldn't have to worry about uppercase
    loveCount = linelist[2]
    loveSucks = loveCount.lower()


# I am pretty sure this is the area where I am getting it wrong?
    if loveCount == 'love':
        loveCount += 1      


# print an unsuccessfull accumulation
    print(loveSucks)
print(loveCount)
```

Comment: What does your desired output look like?

Comment: It's just supposed to count the amount of times the word "love" comes up in a CSV file. Output should be simple, like this problem is, "The total time that love is in the title of a song is ?" I have tried many different combinations, read my notes, watched videos but for something I'm missing the loveTotal in the if statement won't add the sum and print it out. I get it to print the correct number of times love is in each line but I don't know what I'm missing so that it won't display the total.

Answer (score 0):

Several things. First, as a general matter, you'll find that there are, more often than not, multiple ways to get to the same result. Not all those ways are equal, but for now, as a beginner, let's just get it working. With regard to your code, one quick note: When working with files, it is better practice to use a context manager

```
with open('love.csv', mode='r') as file:
    ***Do something here***
```

The context manager will automatically close the file once it has done its thing. Right now, you are calling `open()` on 'love.csv' but you never close it. If the program or the machine were to crash, you could end up with a corrupted file (there are other reasons to close the file as well, but this seems to be the most pressing for most people). Here's a great discussion of context managers. [Context Managers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/). (By the way, Python has a standard library module for working with csv files, but since you don't want to use imported modules, we'll skip that).

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with `loveCount`. You initialize the variable as an int but almost immediately convert it to a string (`loveCount = linelist[2]`). In any event, I've taken a slightly different approach to the question by converting the content of 'love.csv' into a single string, then iterating through the characters to find occurrences of 'love'. The comments do most of the explaining.

```py
# This creates a list of the lines in 'love.csv' as a list of strings

with open('love.csv', mode="r") as file:
    data = file.readlines()

# Create empty string to hold the text from 'data' list

text = ""

# Iterate through data, adding the string in each element to the 'text' 
# variable. Now you have a simple string containing the string content of
#  love.csv

for entry in data:
    text += entry

# Set your counter to 0
count = 0

# In the next step, we're going to iterate through the string 'text' by a
#  moving range of index positions. Each time, we will evaluate 4
#  characters, beginning with text[0:4] (text[i: j]). If that string ==
#  'love' we add 1 to the counter. Then we add 1 to i and j and evaluate
#  text[1:5] to see if it == 'love' and so on.

i = 0
j = 4

# Loop through 'text' until value of j reaches the end of the string

while j <= len(text):
    a = text[i:j]
    if a.lower() == 'love':
        count += 1
    i += 1
    j += 1

print(text)
print(f"Target word count: {count}")
```

You'll note that this approach has the advantage of not having to process the text before using it (i.e. not having to strip punctuation or worry about line breaks). Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help totally. As you may have guessed I am a beginner and learning Python for the very first time. I finally realized my problem and my previous attempts were working. I was using a test file with three lines and I put multiple "love" words within the list / string. See the answer i will now add.

Answer (score 0):

The actual file used was the chart list from Billboard Hot 100, Oct 2021.

```py
file = open("charts.csv")
    file.readline()
    total = 0
    love = "love"
    
    for line in file:
        linelist = line.split(",")
    
        loveIsDumb = linelist[2].lower()
    
        if love in loveIsDumb:
            total += 1
    
print(total,"\nLooking for love in all the wrong places!\n")
```

Output

28